# Why is the text color of my buttons not changing when I tap on them?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to change the text color of my UIButtons to .orange every time a user select one button to show which one is selected. It changes the color back to .white if another button is selected. I tried to subclass the buttons  with the code below but nothing is changing. Using the storyboard and changing the color attribute in the inspector doesn´t work either. What am I missing?

```
class HighlightedButton: UIButton {

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? .orange : UIColor(red: 44/255, green: 62/255, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}

override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        titleLabel?.textColor = isSelected ? .orange : .white
    }
}
```

Comment: self.clipsToBounds = true   try this

Comment: Why don't you use collectionView for such use case?

Comment: @PGDev I used a stack view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create an `Outlet Collection` for all the `buttons` in the `stackView`.

Add an `@IBAction` and connect all the `buttons` to it. In this method, set the `selection` of the `tapped button`. And change the `textColor` of all the `buttons` in the `Outlet Collection` based on their selection, i.e

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!

@IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    buttons.forEach {
        $0.isSelected = ($0 == sender)
        $0.setTitleColor((sender.isSelected) ? .orange : .white, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. But why is my code from above not working? Even when I used the ***setTitleColor*** attribute it didn´t work

Comment: This is because you're just changing the properties of a single button on selection using the custom UIButton. Instead you must handle for all of them.

Comment: Ah ok I see. Thank you!

Comment: forgot to ask something. Is there a way to set the first button as always selected?

Comment: Try calling the ,method manually like `self.onTapButton(buttons.first!)`